# Adding an increment ID field to a SQL Server view

Tags: sql-server-2008

I am trying to create a view from data in a third party system in SQL Server 2008. I am doing this to create a view with geometry on the fly for use in QGIS.

I have discovered that the third party system has allowed duplicates in the primary key column.

Is it possible to create my own incremental column as a primary key in the view?

Comment: Do you have a column that indicates the order? If so, then you could rank over the result.

Comment: If there are duplicates in that column, then it's ***NOT*** the primary key - a primary key **by definition CANNOT** have duplicates

Answer (score 0):

I've discovered that if you use NEWID() AS ID this will create a column that contains a unique identifier.